# Magento 2 admin Uncaught TypeError: this.linksFieldset(...).visible is not a function

Tags: product, admin, javascript, xml, magento2.3.5-p1

When we edit product from admin then its showing loading continue and also getting this error

```
"Uncaught TypeError: this.linksFieldset(...).visible is not a function"
```

is showing error in console. We have opened other product(xyz) it opens without any error.

We just migrate from M1 1.9.3.4 to M2 2.3.5 using data migration tool

**Note**:When i change attribute set directly from database "default to our attribute set(changed attribute_set_id from 4 to 9(database - catalog_product_entity))" then page is open without console error

please check screenshot - 
[image]

Comment: You might be facing this issue only in downloadable products. other product(xyz) might not be downloadable products

Comment: @ChandreshP. i checked product is simple product

Answer (score 0):

You should try to bring one by one attribute which belongs to the **attribute_set_id 4** but not to the **attribute_set_id 9** out of **attribute_id_4**. Therefore, you'll find out the error attribute.